# Difference between C# 6.0 and C#7.0 and the IDE thereof

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ide

I'm trying to understand how the new features C# newer version work.Actually when visual studio 2015 was launched it had new features like for instance NULL Condition operator ( ? ). when i worked using this and pushed the code to the guthub.all others who pulled this code and were using visual studio 2012 couldn't compile the code for the compiler complained about this operator.

I have **three questions** regarding this.

Question 1  is - **does this mean its the new IDE in visual studio 2015 that recognises it i.e its IDE dependent ? IDE understands it and compiles it replacing it with appropriate code.isn't it the .NET framework feature ?**

Question 2 is - **does this mean, if i use a different editor but the same .NET framework it won't work.**

Question 3 is - **aren't newer features that come regularly with new versions of C# dependent on .NET framework ? if not ? where from does it get those feature ?**

please guide about this.how this actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1 is - does this mean its the new IDE in visual studio 2015 that recognises it i.e its IDE dependent ? IDE understands it and compiles it replacing it with appropriate code.isn't it the .NET framework feature ?

The newer IDE, mostly, will be targeting a newer framework of .NET and/or a newer version of the language (C#). Therefore, if the people who are downloading your code do not have the newer IDE, they may not have the newer features of the framework and/or IDE. Ok but what if they installed the newer version of the framework? Then the IDE may not support the newer version of the framework. So the IDE needs to be able to support the newer version of the framework, and the newer version of the framework has to be installed on the machine. Same goes for language.

> Question 2 is - does this mean, if i use a different editor but the same .NET framework it won't work.

Notepad is an editor. So if you have the required framework version and the required language version installed on the machine, and you know how to call the compiler from command line and compile projects and/or solutions then it should work. Same answer as the first question: They need to be able to support it.

> Question 3 is - aren't newer features that come regularly with new versions of C# dependent on .NET framework ? if not ? where from does it get those feature ?

Yes and no. It depends on the feature. For example, in VB.NET the equality operator is `=` (one equal sign). If the language designers decide to introduce another operator for equality, `==`, then they can do this without a new .NET framework. In this case it will be a newer version of VB.NET but it can work with the same old version of the framework.

However, there are cases where a new language feature needs new features from the framework, then it will need the framework version. This depends on the language designers and framework designers to decide whether the effort should go into the language or into the framework. For example, when .NET introduced generic collections, they could have made it so that only C# supports generics and built it into the C# language and NOT the framework. But that would not have been very wise so they made the right decision-now I am not a compiler expert by any means so do not quote me on this but you get the idea of what I am trying to say.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So basically the compiler is a program independent of the .NET framework.It may be containg code to translate this high level code into low level and in between it doesn't need .NET framework ? or it may use it   if it wishes ? but isn't dependent on it ?

Comment: The C# compiler (Roslyn) is written in C# ([bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29)) so if it used features from .NET to do something, and it most likely did, then it will have a dependency on .NET. If you were to write a compiler for C#, most likely you will use one of the many features in .NET so it is highly unlikely that the C# team did not.

Answer (score 0):

These three questions are easily summarized into a single answer: **it's the compiler**.

IDEs provide productivity tools like intellisense and syntax checker, and many other things to make your life easier. Obviously, if an IDE version was created before some language features were introduced, it should find these as syntax errors. Moreover, older IDE versions can target greater .NET Framework / CLR versions using [targeting packs](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html).

There're language features that are just *syntactic sugar* while others require some service provided by the runtime (CLR).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.However , i would like to ask , so basically C# is a different ' _program_ ' independent of .NET framework ? it basically uses some features from .NET framework ?

Comment: @FaheemRasheed C# is a programming language and it has a compiler. The compiled code uses the .NET Framework (and libraries)

Comment: @FaheemRasheed Since C# 6, the compiler is provided also as a service and it has been rewriten in C# itself.